# Why when adding a script to a selected gameobject through another script it's adding the script to each object in the list twice?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateAutomaticGuid : Editor
{
    [MenuItem("GameObject/Generate Guid", false, 11)]
    private static void GenerateGuid()
    {
        foreach (GameObject o in Selection.objects)
        {
            o.AddComponent<GenerateGuid>();
            o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().GenerateGuidNum();
            o.tag = "My Unique ID";
        }
    }
}
```

For example I'm selecting two gameobjects in the hierarchy right click and GenerateGuid I use a break point and it's making a loop on each object in the list Selection.objects twice so each object in the list have the script GenerateGuid twice. And I want it to add the script to each object once only.

This is the GenerateGuid script :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateGuid : MonoBehaviour, IStateQuery
{
    public string uniqueGuidID;
    public SaveLoad saveLoad;
    public GameObject naviParent;

    private Guid guidID;
    private bool isNaviChildOfKid = false;
   
    public void GenerateGuidNum()
    {
        guidID = Guid.NewGuid();
        uniqueGuidID = guidID.ToString();
    }

    private State m_state = new State();

    public Guid UniqueId => Guid.Parse("E0B03C9C-9680-4E02-B06B-E227831CB33F");

    private class State
    {
        public bool naviInHand;
    }

    public string GetState()
    {
        return JsonUtility.ToJson(m_state);
    }

    public void SetState(string jsonString)
    {
        m_state = JsonUtility.FromJson<State>(jsonString);

        if (m_state.naviInHand == true)
        {
            transform.GetComponent<InteractableItem>().distance = 0;
            transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform;//rig_f_middle;
            transform.localPosition = GameObject.Find("Navi Parent").transform.localPosition;
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.001f, 0.001f, 0.001f);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if(transform.IsChildOf(naviParent.transform) == false && isNaviChildOfKid == false)
        {
            m_state.naviInHand = true;
            saveLoad.Save();

            isNaviChildOfKid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

A screenshot of all the places I'm calling the GenerateGuid :

[image: All places GenerateGuid is being called or used]

Comment: if you have three objects selected, does it add three GUIDs? It's been a while since I touched Editor code but I seem to recall this being an issue; I believe the context menu is called on each selected object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you executing `GenerateGuid` twice or by amount of gameobjects?
Can you show all places where you executing `GenerateGuid`

Comment: I added a screenshot to my question of where I'm calling the GenerateGuid script or using. In two places I'm doing GetComponent to get this script and use it. In other two places are in the GenerateAutomaticGuid editor script.  And I'm not calling anywhere to GenerateAutomaticGuid just using it with right click mouse when selecting objects.

Comment: And I used a break point if for example in the list there are two items it will loop 4 times. but there are two items.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a null check to your foreach loop to see if your object already has a GenerateGuid component and skip the process if it does:

```
    foreach (GameObject o in Selection.objects)
    {
      if(!o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>()){
          o.AddComponent<GenerateGuid>();
          o.GetComponent<GenerateGuid>().GenerateGuidNum();
          o.tag = "My Unique ID";
      }
    }
```

It won't prevent your function from being called multiple times but it can prevent duplicate GenerateGuid components.